# Store Photographs Taken via Android App in the App Data

Tags: android

I am writing an Android app that uses the device's camera to allow the user to take a photograph. The app does not have a custom activity for using the camera, but rather interacts with the device's native camera UI to acquire the image.

Currently, I am using the following code to acquire photos taken by the user:

```
// Does the device have a camera activity to handle the photograph intent?
if(takePhotoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create a file object for the image to be stored in and launch the camera activity.
    File imageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            "/Android/data/my.app.package.name");
    File photoFile = new File(imageFolder, "StackOverflowIsTheBest.jpg");
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

The problem with this is that right now, I am storing the images on the device's external storage. While this works, it is not what I want to do. I want to store the images as part of the app's app data so that when the user resets the app, the images are erased. How could I go about doing this? I have looked at the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) page in the Android Developer Documentation, but I cannot figure out how to apply it to my project.

Comment: Do you want  to store the camera images in a file and want to retrieve them later?

Comment: @CrazyAndroid Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: In that case it is better to use Content Provider.@David

Comment: @CrazyAndroid Very well, but how would I use them for what I want to achieve?